# Linux abstract socket refuse connection on SOCK_DGRAM

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, posix

I am writing a simple client-server app using AF_UNIX sockets, but my code does not work. When I want to send to socket I get transport endpoint not connected error. Any advices?

SERVER:

```
struct sockaddr_un addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
strcpy(addr.sun_path+1,"example");
addr.sun_path[0]=0;
int mysock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if((bind(mysock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)))<0)
{
  perror("bind() error");
  return false;
}
if (send(mysock, path, sizeof(path), 0)<0)
{
  perror("send");
}
```

CLIENT:

```
struct sockaddr_un addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
int mysock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(mysock<0)
{
  perror("socket() error");
  return false;
}
addr.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
strcpy(addr.sun_path+1,"example");
addr.sun_path[0]=0;
if((connect(mysock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)))<0)
{
  perror("connects() error");
  return false;
}
recv(mysock, buf, sizeof(buf),0);
printf("%s\n",buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't connected the server side. Binding a socket to an address establishes the address of the *local* peer. However, immediately after binding the socket, you're doing a `send` but you haven't specified a destination. I.e. where is the data to be sent?

Furthermore, Unix domain *datagram* sockets are different than others in that both sides need to establish a local address before bidirectional data transfer can occur.

So each side needs to create a socket and `bind` it to an address of their choosing. The client side can then either `connect` to the server's address (which permanently establishes the destination address), or it may use `sendto` to specify the destination address for each buffer.

The server will typically use `recvfrom` to receive data *and* the client's address, then use `sendto` to return the response to the client.

For the sake of clarity, this example in python3. Server code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(b'\x00server')            # Our address
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
print("Data:", data)
print("Client Address:", addr)
sock.sendto(data, addr)
```

Client code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(b'\x00client')      # Our address
sock.connect(b'\x00server')   # Server's address
data = b"Hello"
sock.send(data)
print("Sent", data)
rdata, saddr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
print("ReturnedData:", rdata)
print("ServerAddr returned:", saddr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> transport not connected

You can't use `send()` on an unconnected UDP socket. You need to either `connect()` it or use `sendto()`. This is all documented.

NB What does 'Linux abstract socket' mean? I don't see anything abstract about your code. You are also lacking error-checking on `recv()`, which needs to be `recvfrom()` if the socket is unconnected.

Comment: OP meant "abstract namespace". From `unix(7)`: "Traditionally, UNIX domain sockets can be either unnamed, or bound to a filesystem pathname (marked as being of type socket).  Linux also  supports an abstract namespace which is independent of the filesystem." .... "an abstract socket address is distinguished ... by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte (0)."